# Deploying Python script that use google-api-python-client library as Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-scheduler

I've created a Python script that use [google-api-python-client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) to pull data from my DFA account.

I would like to deploy this script to **Google Cloud Scheduler** so I can run this script on a daily basis. When I deployed the **Cloud Function**, I received an error that said:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "googleapiclient".

After I've added `"googleapiclient"` to the `requirements.txt` and deployed it again, I got a new error that said it couldn't find the `googleapiclient` library to add.

May I ask if it's possible to install the `googleapiclient` library under the Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to install and use the `googleapiclient` library in **GCP**. Use `googleapiclient` **module** when importing the **Google API Client** in your python code.

```py
import googleapiclient
```

Then add the `google-api-python-client` in your **requirements.txt**

```py
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-api-python-client
```

You may check this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/0b0d4760ecee68614417e21c3805c906ab433973/auth/api-client/snippets.py#L23) from `github` that uses the `googleapiclient` module and this [requirements.txt](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/0b0d4760ecee68614417e21c3805c906ab433973/auth/api-client/requirements.txt#L1).

Comment: Oh thx!!! I was adding googleapiclient in the requirements.txt instead of google-api-python-client, that's why it's not working. Thanks so much for your prompt reseponse!